# Recursive lookup of a binary in current directory's parents through hierarchical $PATH

Tags: shell, command-line, path

I want to have some extra binaries / command available when I'm on terminal, triggered by the CWD.

Let following be the directory structure as one example

```
├── P1
|   ├── mybin
|   │   └── cmd1
|   ├── S1
|   │   └── mybin
|   │       └── cmd2
|   ├── S2
└── P2
    └── S3
```

Then in this directory structure

- `cmd1` and `cmd2` are available in `P1/S1`.
- only `cmd1` is available in `P1` or `P1/S2`.
- neither is available in `P2` or `P2/S3`

In general, I want this to work with any directory structure. This is similar to how git detects if you're in a git repository. It's equivalent to putting `./mybin`, `../mybin`, `../../mybin` on `$PATH`.

How should I modify my `PATH` so that this works? I'm using the fish shell, but I'll be happy to port a solution from any other shell to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you're not happy with just

```
PATH="./mybin:../mybin:../../mybin:../../../mybin:$PATH"
```

until some limit like 8 or so sub-directories.

Instead of polluting and breaking your regular command lookup, I suggest you use a short wrapper, such that the recursive lookup will only be done for the commands prefixed by it.

Eg. `k foo` will try `./mybin/foo`, `../mybin/foo`, etc. but simply `foo` will be looked up in `$PATH`, as usual.

But I'm not using fish, and I have no idea how that could be written in the fish shell's language. With bash / ksh / zsh, it could be something like:

```
function k {
    typeset p=. cmd=$1; shift
    while
        typeset e=$p/mybin/$cmd
        if [ -x "$e" ]; then "$e" "$@"; return; fi 
        [ ! "$p" -ef / ]
    do
        p=../$p
    done
    echo >&2 "k: not found: $cmd"; return 1
}
```

If that works, you could make it into a standalone executable script, instead of trying to translate it to fish:

```
#! /bin/bash
p=. cmd=$1; shift
while
    e=$p/mybin/$cmd
    if [ -x "$e" ]; then exec "$e" "$@"; fi
    [ ! "$p" -ef / ]
do
    p=../$p
done
echo >&2 "k: not found: $cmd"; exit 1
```

Comment: Even though it's solution to slightly modified version of the problem, I think this is good enough. Comes at the expense of brevity but with the benefit of simplicity.